# React app won't stop loading. Browser console full of errors

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, cdn

I am trying to make a react website and it randomly stopped loading on my browser. The console displays a long list of errors. Most of these are: "tabTarget is null" and "Unchecked lastError value: Error: Unexpected error occured".

I can't seem to find similar problems. Below is my code for App.js, Footer.js, and Index.js.

App.js

```
import React from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/Container';
import Navbar from 'react-bootstrap/Navbar';
import Nav from 'react-bootstrap/Nav';
//import NavbarBrand from 'react-bootstrap/NavbarBrand';
import './App.css';

import Footer from './components/Footer';

class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      title: 'My name',
      headerLInks: [
        {title: 'Home', path: '/'},
        {title: 'About', path: '/about'},
        {title: 'Contact', path: '/contact'},
      ],
      home: {
        title: 'Be Relentless',
        subTitle: 'Projects that make a difference',
        text: 'Checkout my projects below'
      },
      about: {
        title: 'About me'
      },
      contact: {
        title: 'Let\'s talk'
      }
    }
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Router>
        <Container className='p-0' fluid={true}>

          <Navbar className='border-bottom' bg="transparent" expand="lg">
            <Navbar.Brand>My Name</Navbar.Brand>

            <Navbar.Toggle className="border-0" aria-controls="navbar-toggle" />
            <Navbar.Collapse id="navbar-toggle">
              <Nav className="ml-auto">
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/">Home</Link>
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/about">About</Link>
                <Link className="nav-link" to="/contact">Contact</Link>
              </Nav>
            </Navbar.Collapse>
          </Navbar>

          <Footer />

        </Container>
      </Router>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Footer.js

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/esm/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

function Footer() {
    return (
        <Footer className="mt-5">
            <Container fluid={true}>
                <Row classNam="border-top justify-content-between p-3">
                    <Col className="p-0" md={3} sm={12}>
                        My name
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </Footer>
    )
}

export default Footer;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';

import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);

reportWebVitals();
```

Comment: have you restarted your computer?

Comment: I have. No changes. I am trying to reverse engineer what I've done. So far, no changes.

Answer (score 2):

You are calling the Footer function within itself which causes the loop.  Change the Footer function to the following:

```
    function Footer() {
    return (
            <Container fluid={true}>
                <Row classNam="border-top justify-content-between p-3">
                    <Col className="p-0" md={3} sm={12}>
                        My name
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
    )
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Just change your footer to html or another tag for example:

```
import React from 'react';
import Container from 'react-bootstrap/esm/Container';
import Row from 'react-bootstrap/Row';
import Col from 'react-bootstrap/Col';

function Footer() {
    return (
        <footer className="mt-5">
            <Container fluid={true}>
                <Row classNam="border-top justify-content-between p-3">
                    <Col className="p-0" md={3} sm={12}>
                        My name
                    </Col>
                </Row>
            </Container>
        </footer>
    )
}
```